# Continuous function complex that does not have primitive.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need an example of a continuous function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that does not have a primitive.

Comment: Sounds like a problem. What do you know, in general, about functions that do not have a primitive? What is stopping you from doing any work at all on *this* question?

Comment: I do not think that there is a counterexample. Every function $f$ that is continuous has an antiderivative.

Comment: Do you mean, a function $g$ such that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} = f$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $F$ is holomorphic  $\Longrightarrow$ $F'$ is holomorphic (Cauchy Integral Formula)
$$F'(z)=f(z) =\overline{z}$$